# Server dropped connection unexpectedly with certain WiFi

Tags: network, wifi

> OS: Yosemite
>
> Type: Macbook Air 11

I have 2 WiFi's (A and B). Whenever I connect to A, my Mac drops the connection to a certain websites and often loses connection to the WiFi. But when I connect to B, everything's fine. No disconnection and no "server dropped connection unexpectedly".

This situation does not happen when I connect to the same websites with Windows.

Why is this happening and what can I do to solve the problems when connecting to A?

I tried restarting WiFi but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Probably need to state what routers or APs are providing the signal for each.  I suspect one either connects at 5ghz and the other only 2.4, or it could be some other difference in the signal provided.  Wifi is not just wifi...there are MANY variants.

Comment: I'm getting some information.

Comment: How do I get those? I tried finding it but, well, I can't see what info I should get. (Noob at these stuffs)